# SQL Having count distinct with two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

To make it simple I use AdventureWorks database for this example:

```
SELECT p.Title
FROM Person.Person p
GROUP BY p.Title
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.LastName) > 1
```

I struggle to figure out how to add firstname to last name into `DISTINCT`, so that count distinct would be based on both of those columns rather than just lastname. Issue is that I group by on the column different from those in the `COUNT DISTINCT (p.Title here)`.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `count(distinct)` doesn't take multiple arguments in SQL Server, a work around is to concatenate them together:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(p.LastName, ' ', p.FirstName)) > 1
```

Comment: Why can't you just `group by p.Title, p.LastName, p.FirstName` then `distinct p.Title`

Answer (score 3):

What @GordonLinoff says is a workaround, it does work in this case but it's not necessarily efficient. It also doesn't work if you have dates or numbers.

The more correct way of doing this is to group first by `FirstName` and `LastName` also, then group again just over the `Title`:

```sql
SELECT p.Title
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT p.Title, p.LastName, p.FirstName
    FROM Person.Person p
) p
GROUP BY p.Title
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: @lptr Righto, the count needs to go on the outside. Have fixed